# Wordpress and current_menu_item

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason, menus within a widget in Wordpress do not get assigned classes such as the "current_menu_item" class - on top of that, when adding a class to the menu item in Worddpress > Appearance > Menu, they are not assigned the respective classes.

I want to be able to assign a current_page_item class, or any class for that matter, to highlight a currently active menu item within a widget. I'm not sure why classes are omitted from menus within a widget, but i guess it's an oversight from the developers or something.

Can anyone help me achieve the above?

Regards,
Nick.

Comment: Not a lot. I can now add classes to menu items, but i realised that doesn't help one bit, as i assume some form of PHP defines the current_menu_item in the menu. Really don't understand why current_menu_item isn't present in widgetized menus.

Comment: Do you have it live somewhere, can you give url ??

Comment: http://n8geeks.com/jason/bill-payment/ the menu in question is the one on the left side

Comment: current-menu-item **is** on the list-item of your Bill Payments. Did you fix it in the process of asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#access .current-menu-item > a,
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is where you're styling your .current-menu-item to be bold. However, your menu on the left is not inside the access nav element. The current-menu-item class **is** on your active menu item:

```html
<li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-40"><a href="/jason/bill-payment">Bill Payment</a></li>
```

Comment: Fantastic, not sure why i missed this. Got it working now, thanks Gaz.

Comment: Actually, i now need something else. How do i assign a background image to an li? I know how to do this via CSS, obviously, but i cannot seem to change the code you mentioned above to be in line with what i need i.e.

    #access .current-menu-item > li,
    #access .current-menu-ancestor > li,
    #access .current_page_item > li,
    #access .current_page_ancestor > li {
    background: url(blah.png);
    }

Comment: Could it be that you're missing a closing bracket on the style where you define the background-image?

Comment: It appears not Gaz, i guess maybe the li is not an option in Wordpress for whatever reason, because obviously php somewhere defines the current page item, i guess they just haven't bothered adding the ability to do this with li's, i could be wrong though.

I managed to do what i wanted by hacking the > a code, but it's not ideal, so if anyone can still help it would be greatly appreciated.